# Convert this String into hashmap

Tags: java

Let's say I have an array of strings like this

```
String[] strings =  {"game_2times",
                     "game_3times",
                     "game_4times",
                     "listy_bubenicek",
                     "listy_peneznieso"};
```

What I want is to create a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` to hold the keys and the values. The key and value of each string are separated by a `"_"`. The resultant map for the above strings should look like the following:

```
"game"  ->  ["2times", "3times", "4times"]
"listy" ->  ["bubenicek", "peneznieso"]
```

I tried this

```
for (String item: names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
        if(names[i].contains("game")) {
            c.add(item);
        }
        hashmap.put(item.split("_")[0],c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a hashmap if you only have one key?

Comment: I have bunch of sound files  in such format. I need to split them into categries and actual names. with cats i do render LayoutTabs and with actual names i do render the actual buttons. There is no single key.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The way I read the example, there are two keys: `"game"` and '"listy"`.  But the key / value part of the example shows only the first key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using streams.

```
String[] strings = {
        "game_2times","game_3times","game_4times","listy_bubenicek",
        "listy_peneznieso"
};
```

- stream the string array using [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D))
- Use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split each string on the `_` to create an array of `s[]` of the two elements
- use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to group based on a key, in this case, `s[0]`
- then use [Collectors.mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to map to `s[1]` and put in a list.

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(strings)
        .map(str -> str.split("_"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],
                Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], Collectors.toList())));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
game=[2times, 3times, 4times]
listy=[bubenicek, peneznieso]
```

Here is another option sans streams.

- create a map to hold the results
- Iterate thru the array, splitting the string as before.
- [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) will use the supplied argument as a key if it isn't present and will create and return the value of the function, in this case, an ArrayList.
- then this and subsequent references to that key will add the value to the list for that key.

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
for(String str : strings) {
    String[] strArray = str.split("_");
    result.computeIfAbsent(strArray[0], v->new ArrayList<>()).add(strArray[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thats what i was looking for. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are more elegant ways of doing this but I will show the simple to understand way:

```
    public static Map<String, List<String>> flatten(List<String> names) {
    final Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String item : names) {
        final String[] parts = item.split("_");
        if (result.containsKey(parts[0])) {
            result.get(parts[0]).add(parts[1]);
        } else {
            final ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
            c.add(parts[1]);
            result.put(parts[0], c);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to also show the more elegant version then =)

Comment: WJS gave the 2 elegant ones using Streams and computeIfAbsent. But considering the OP was struggling with basic Java I think this is the better one.